# Unexpected asynchronous action in "" computed property vue/no-async-in-computed-properties Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am developing my project with Vue3 , I am getting this error while running, here is my whole code . Can someone help me fix it. Thank you guys

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  name: "RegisterView",
  data() {
    return {
      user: {
        username: "",
        password: "",
        email: "",
        phoneNumber: "",
        role: "",
      },
      role : []
    };
  },computed:{
    getRole(){
       axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/role/get').then(res=>{
        this.role = res.data;
      })
      return [];
    }
  },
  methods: {
    register() {
      axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/user/register", this.user).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```
// Error  Unexpected asynchronous action in "getRole" computed property  vue/no-async-in-computed-properties
```

I tried async and await , but it seems I got it wrong

Comment: computed property are not designed to do async calls, you could use another lifecycle hook or watch

Comment: Can you give me an example so I can try it?I'm new to Javascript

Comment: Please let me know what do you want to achieve? and how do you want to use that getRole property?

Comment: I want to read the API in the desktop to be able to get the Role list and use a v-for loop to display that list

Answer (score 1):

Try to run that call inside the `created` hook :

```js
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  name: "RegisterView",
  data() {
    return {
      user: {
        username: "",
        password: "",
        email: "",
        phoneNumber: "",
        role: "",
      },
      role : []
    };
  },
   created(){
     this.getRole():
  },
  methods: {
    getRole(){
       axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/role/get').then(res=>{
        this.role = res.data;
      }).catch(err=>{
          this.role = []
      })
    
    },
    register() {
      axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/user/register", this.user).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      });
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: I tried your way and it worked, can you explain more why it's running so I can know what's the problem, thank you

Comment: computed properties are used to get new property based on other one, mathematically we could say that's the new property is calculated by adding new factors to another properties. created/mounted hook are use to initialize the component data based on asyn/sync calls

Answer (score 0):

GetRole uses promises, meaning it doesn't have immediate value but has side-effects, which is considered to be dirty code by the linter (code quality checker)

If you need async computed, use asyncComputed instead, which has immediate value and gets updated of promise resolution automatically
https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed for Options API, @vueuse/core for Composition API

Comment: After I changed it to asyncComputed it stopped giving me the error, but the return of res.data is [] , even though there are 3 records in my api

Comment: Did you forgot to remove a copy in `computed` by a chance?